# Extracting coefficients from exponential function

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, coefficients

I would like to extract the coefficients A,b0,b1,b2 from the following form:

A0 * Exp [b0 + b1*x + b2*x^2]

I am aware that the command Coefficient or CoefficientList would be able to do so for polynomials. Is there a way to do the same for the expression above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
forms = {A0*Exp[b0 + b1*x + b2*x^2],
         Exp[b0 + b1*x + b2*x^2],
         asd asdd Exp[b x^2]};

FirstCase[#, Exp[b__] a_. :> {a, CoefficientList[b, x]}, {}, {0}] & /@ forms // Column
```

> {A0, {b0, b1, b2}}
>   {1, {b0, b1, b2}}
>   {asd asdd, {0, 0, b}}

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the `TreeForm` function to visualize and the `Part` function to get the parameters. For example, here is your expression:

```
expr = A0*Exp[b0 + b1*x + b2*x^2]
```

Let us apply the `TreeForm` to it:

```
TreeForm[expr]
```

It returns the tree:

[image]

From this image you clearly see that the tree coordinate of `A0` is `{1}`,
and of, say, `b0` is `{2,2,1}`. Indeed,

```
expr[[1]]

(* A0  *)
```

and

```
expr[[2, 2, 1]]

(*  b0  *)
```

And the same you can apply to any other part of the expression.

Have fun!